# Какую архитектуру нейронной сети использовать?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Имеется датасет: https://drive.google.com/open?id=15pxnmsjNEr9-n1gjU0OWyS7gMNQT5ePL
Нужно подобрать конфигурацию сверхточной сети. Ранее использоваться такой вариант:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Он доказал свою полную не эффективность, не распознавались знаки 1,2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня точность модели на ваших тестовых данных составила 100%, что очень подозрительно. Похоже валидационная и тестовая выборки являются подмножеством обучающей выборки. В машинном обучении это называется [Data Leakage](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/).

Такая НС будет, с высокой степенью вероятности, очень плохо предсказывать картинки, которые ей не попадались при обучении.

Чтобы это исправить надо убедиться что все три множества (обучающий, валидационный и тестовый наборы данных) не пересекаются - т.е. не содержат одинаковых картинок.

Архитектура НС:

```
Model summary
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 32)        896
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 12, 12, 64)        18496
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_8 (MaxPooling2 (None, 6, 6, 64)          0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_11 (Dropout)         (None, 6, 6, 64)          0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 4, 4, 32)          18464
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_9 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 2, 32)          0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 128)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 64)                8256
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_12 (Dropout)         (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 7)                 455
=================================================================
Total params: 46,567
Trainable params: 46,567
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Процесс обучения:

```
Epoch 1/10
109/109 [==============================] - 6s 56ms/step - loss: 0.4183 - acc: 0.8598 - val_loss: 1.1637e-04 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 2/10
109/109 [==============================] - 4s 36ms/step - loss: 0.0156 - acc: 0.9963 - val_loss: 1.6703e-05 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 3/10
109/109 [==============================] - 4s 36ms/step - loss: 0.0107 - acc: 0.9973 - val_loss: 5.0050e-06 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 4/10
109/109 [==============================] - 4s 36ms/step - loss: 0.0055 - acc: 0.9983 - val_loss: 3.9538e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 5/10
109/109 [==============================] - 4s 36ms/step - loss: 0.0082 - acc: 0.9981 - val_loss: 4.7002e-06 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 6/10
109/109 [==============================] - 4s 36ms/step - loss: 0.0056 - acc: 0.9986 - val_loss: 4.8429e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 7/10
109/109 [==============================] - 4s 36ms/step - loss: 0.0069 - acc: 0.9976 - val_loss: 2.8554e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 8/10
109/109 [==============================] - 4s 36ms/step - loss: 0.0024 - acc: 0.9994 - val_loss: 1.2755e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 9/10
109/109 [==============================] - 4s 36ms/step - loss: 0.0024 - acc: 0.9991 - val_loss: 1.2278e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 10/10
109/109 [==============================] - 4s 35ms/step - loss: 0.0029 - acc: 0.9992 - val_loss: 1.1966e-07 - val_acc: 1.0000
Out[16]: <keras.callbacks.History at 0x22aea296208>
```

Проверка на проверочной выборке:

```
In [18]: model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, test_generator.samples // batch_size)
Out[18]: [6.057144740081878e-05, 1.0]
```

---

Полный код:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

path = Path(r'D:\work\SO_ru\939604-CNN_Pictures')
input_shape = (30, 30, 3)
target_size = (30, 30)
batch_size = 64
epochs = 10

os.chdir(str(path))

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'train',
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'val',
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'test',
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')


model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(train_generator.num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Model summary')
print(model.summary())

# generate our neural-network
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=val_generator.samples // batch_size)

model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, test_generator.samples // batch_size)
```