# Обучение модели по картинкам

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, распознавание-образов

Можно ли обучить нейронную сеть по картинкам разной размерности, например, для бинарной классификации? Стоит ли подгонять файлы .jpg под один размер(например, 28х28 или 150х150)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вам уже ответили - да, при подаче картинок на вход НС все они должны иметь одинаковый размер. Многие модули, например Keras или PyTorch, умеют это делать "на лету".

**Теперь пару слов о том почему это необходимо:**

Обучение нейросети для классификации картинок сводится к подбору оптимальных весов. Все картинки обучающего набора нейросети представлены как 3D (один цветовой канал) или 4D (три цветовых канала) матрица / тензор. Для того чтобы иметь возможность составить такой тензор размерность всех картинок должна совпадать. Только тогда можно склеить 1000 монохромных картинок размерности `(32, 32)` в 3D тензор размерности `(1000, 32, 32)` или 1000 цветных картинок (3 цветовых канала) размерности `(32, 32, 3)` в 4D тензор размерности `(1000, 32, 32, 3)`. Все это сделано для упрощения и оптимизации скорости работы НС. Гораздо проще и быстрее делать арифметические операции на уровне многомерных тензоров по сравнению с обработкой отдельных матриц в цикле. Для этого существуют готовые библиотеки и даже специально разработанные для этого графические процессоры.

Comment: Можно ли с помощью с помощью Keras или Pytorch сжать, растянуть, т.е. подогнать все картинки под один размер? Или каждую в ручную обрабатывать?

Comment: @СергейЕршов, [пример для Keras](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/939732/211923)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, придется подгонять картинки под один размер, ведь нейросеть может неправильно распознать картинку другого размера. 
Но, я возможно могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 0):

В любом случае придётся подгонять изображения под один размер, что бы обучить. А так же нужно будет нормировать изображения. Общий материал про СНС можно прочитать по  [ссыле](https://towardsdatascience.com/covolutional-neural-network-cb0883dd6529):

> Normalize the data between 0–1 by dividing train data and test data with 255 then convert all labels into one-hot vector with to_catagorical() function.
>   It has 50,000 training data and 10,000 testing image data. Image size in CIFAR-10 is 32 x 32 x 3. It comes with Keras library.

А в целом пройдите курс на условном курсера или аналогичном ресурсе.

Answer (score 0):

Если для полносвязной то входной вектор=<ширина> * <высота>,все картинки должны иметь одинаковую <высота> и <ширина>.