# Как отобразить результат модели?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras, классификация

Есть обученная модель. Определяет где машина, где велосипед. Решил проверить на тестовых изображениях (их три, они расположены в директории, указанной в `test_path`).

Код срабатывает, никакой ошибки не выдает, но и результат отсутствует.

```
test_path = 'C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\test_images'
imgs_path = glob.glob(test_path + '\\*.jpg')

model = keras.models.load_model('C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\model1.h5')

for i in imgs_path:

  img = image.load_img(i, target_size=(36, 36))
  img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img)
  img_tensor = np.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)
  img_tensor /= 255.
  prediction = model.predict(img_tensor)
  print (prediction)
```

То есть, должно выдать три результата по очереди.

Answer (score 4):

Создайте генератор для тестовых картинок.

```
test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/path/to/test/images',
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, test_generator.samples // batch_size)
```

NOTE: тестовые картинки должны находится в поддиректориях c точно такими же названиями как и картинки из обучающего набора.

PS [рабочий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/939732/211923)

---

**UPD:** для того, чтобы классифицировать незнакомые картинки:

```
img_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/path/to/images/for/classification',
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

probabilities = model.predict_generator(generator, 
                                        img_generator.samples // batch_size)
```

Comment: Благодарю, не совсем понятно, разве модель не сама должна распределить их, где машина, а где велосипед. Зачем поддиректории?

Comment: @Алекс, поддиректории для того, чтобы определить правильно ли модель классифицирует тестовые картинки - по именам поддиректорий определяется правильность классификации классов.

Comment: а результат от 0 до 1; получается, если ближе к 1 (больше 0.5), то модель уверена, что на фото, то, что мы ищем, если < 0.5, то наоборот; 0.5 - модель сомневается? Не подскажите, как интерпретировать? @MaxU

Comment: @Алекс, пример: 0.67 - модель считает, что с вероятностью 67% картинка принадлежит определенному классу.

Comment: И результат отображается в соответствии с местоположением в директории? Например 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg и получили [0.5;0.6;0.7]. Получается с вероятностью 0.5 на изображении 1.jpg есть искомый предмет, с вероятностью 0.6 ... @MaxU